# Problem at the onchange function in the main component, when I type on the keyboard inside the input, the page refreshes itself

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The problem with the code is that when I type on the keyboard inside the input the page flickers and is refreshed.

The code I'm struggling with is this :

```
 this.state = {
      search: "",
    };
changedInput = (e) => {
    // //change the state of search for the input
    // this.setState({search:e.target.value})
    
    this.setState({ search: e.target.value });
  };
 <ul style={{ display: this.state.contactsDisplay }}></ul>
        <label>
          <span>search</span>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="form_name"
            id="name"
            
             value={this.state.search}
            onChange={(e)=>{this.changedInput(e)}}
          />
        </label>
```

Here is the full code: the main component calls the class component of listContacts which just presents the contacts one after the other

```
class main extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  needUpdate: "false",
  showEmptyStr: "none",
  formDisplay: "none",
  formMode: "new", //new or edit
  listDisplay: "block",
  caption: "all contacts",
  contactsDisplay: "block",
  nameOfSelectedContact: "",
  telOfSelectedContact: "",
  addressOfSelectedContact: "",
  freeTextOfSelectedContact: "",
  mailOfSelectedContact: "",
  photoOfSelectedContact: "",
  displaySelectedContact: "none",
  search: "",
};
   this.changeNeedUpdate = this.changeNeedUpdate.bind(this);
   this.checkIfBookEmpty = this.checkIfBookEmpty.bind(this);
   this.changeFormDisplayEdit = 
  this.changeFormDisplayEdit.bind(this);
   this.changeFullDisplayContact = 
 this.changeFullDisplayContact.bind(this);
   this.changeFormDisplay = this.changeFormDisplay.bind(this);
   this.changecontactsDisplay = this.changecontactsDisplay.bind(this);
   this.TOGGLElISTfULL = this.TOGGLElISTfULL.bind(this);

   this.setSelectedContact = this.setSelectedContact.bind(this);
   }
  showContactsInLIst = () => {
//show contacts in a way so they are item in list
let code = "";
code = contactArray.map((item) => (
  <ContactInList
    key={uuidv4()}
    name={item.name}
    address={item.address}
    mail={item.mail}
    photo={item.photo}
    freeText={item.freeText}
    tel={item.tel}
    // search={this.state.search}
    contactDisplay={this.state.contactDisplay}
    changeFormDisplayOneContact={this.changeFormDisplayOneContact}
    changeConDisplay={this.TOGGLElISTfULL}
    setSelectedContact={this.setSelectedContact}
    changeFormDisplayEdit={this.changeFormDisplayEdit}
    changeNeedUpdateMain={this.changeNeedUpdate}
    checkIfBookEmpty={this.checkIfBookEmpty}
    />
   ));

   return code;
 };
   changedInput = (e) => {
    // //change the state of search for the input
      // this.setState({search:e.target.value})

     this.setState({ search: e.target.value });
 };

   render() {
   return (
  <main>
    <button onClick={this.changeFormDisplayInsert}>insert 
         contact</button>

    <h2>{this.state.caption}</h2>
    <h3 style={{ display: this.state.showEmptyStr }}>empty phone 
    book</h3>

    <Form
      formVisibility={this.state.formDisplay}
      formMode={this.state.formMode}
      name={this.state.nameOfSelectedContact}
      photo={this.state.photoOfSelectedContact}
      address={this.state.addressOfSelectedContact}
      mail={this.state.mailOfSelectedContact}
      tel={this.state.telOfSelectedContact}
      freeText={this.state.freeTextOfSelectedContact}
      setSelectedContact={this.setSelectedContact}
      changeFormDisplay={this.changeFormDisplay}
      changeNeedUpdate={this.changeNeedUpdate}
    />
    <ul style={{ display: this.state.contactsDisplay }}></ul>
    <label>
      <span>search</span>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="form_name"
        id="name"
        value={this.state.search}
        onChange={(e) => {
          this.changedInput(e);
        }}
      />
    </label>
    {this.showContactsInLIst()}
    <ContactFull
      name={this.state.nameOfSelectedContact}
      photo={this.state.photoOfSelectedContact}
      address={this.state.addressOfSelectedContact}
      mail={this.state.mailOfSelectedContact}
      tel={this.state.telOfSelectedContact}
      freeText={this.state.freeTextOfSelectedContact}
      changecontactsDisplay={this.changecontactsDisplay}
      displayFull={this.state.displaySelectedContact}
      TOGGLElISTfULL={this.TOGGLElISTfULL}
       />
     </main>
      );
      }
      }
```

Comment: Would be helpful is you posted all of the code. I'm not sure what `contactsDisplay` does for instance. Are you able to post more? 

Also, just looking at your code, you don't have to do an inline function for `changedInput`. You can just write `onChange={this.changedInput}`.

Comment: hi i edited  the post so it will show the whole code by the way all components i used are class components, thank you for the help

Comment: Thanks for that :) So are you effectively trying show an updated list based on what the user types in the input?

Comment: yes i'm trying to show only componets with name that equale to the search input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so because that's a hell of a lot of code :D I'm going to post two simplified options you can take.

I'd suggest you try using [React hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html) instead of class based components. You definitely don't have to! But I find it to be much simpler. Give their [new beta docs site](https://beta.reactjs.org/) a look, it's very good.

For a hooks-based approach, I'd try something like this:

```
import { useState } from "react";

// data we'll be using for our search
const data = [
  { id: 1, item: "foo", desc: "im a foo child!" },
  { id: 2, item: "bar", desc: "im a bar child!" },
  { id: 3, item: "baz", desc: "im a baz child!" }
];

const Parent = () => {
  // set up a search variable using the useState hook
  // we'll capture what's in the input and apply that
  // to a filter function below 
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState("");

  // a change function to update the search term
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setSearchValue(e.target.value);
  };

  // this function will take the data we want to 
  // iterate over. it'll basically say, does whatever
  // item we're iterating over, match the search term? 
  // if it does, then return a new array with only those 
  // values inside. 
  const updatedList = data.filter(({ item }) => {
    return item.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase());
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" value={searchValue} onChange={handleChange} />
      {updatedList.map(({ id, item, desc }) => (
        <Child key={id} item={item} desc={desc} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

const Child = ({ item, desc }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>{item}</h2>
      <p>{desc}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Now. I know you've gone for a class-based approach, so here's the same thing using that:

```
import { Component } from "react";

const data = [
  { id: 1, item: "foo", desc: "im a foo child!" },
  { id: 2, item: "bar", desc: "im a bar child!" },
  { id: 3, item: "baz", desc: "im a baz child!" }
];

class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      searchValue: ""
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      searchValue: e.target.value
    });
  }

  render() {
    const updatedList = data.filter(({ item }) => {
      return item.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchValue.toLowerCase());
    });

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <input
          type="text"
          value={this.state.searchValue}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        {updatedList.map(({ id, item, desc }) => (
          <Child key={id} item={item} desc={desc} />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Child = ({ item, desc }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>{item}</h2>
      <p>{desc}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

You see in both example the `<Child />` component is separate? That's what you'll need to do; just make sure the child component receives props and the parent component can deal with the logic of filtering.

Does that make sense?

Comment: wow!!!!! thank you very much you are the greatest!! :)

Answer (score 0):

move  Component outside the current react.
it happened because whenever the state of the current Component changes it will refresh its dom tree. And when the dom will rerender the functional component will be executed again that's why you'll always lose the focus of the input but you never lose the state of the component.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: hi thanks for the help, the component is not a functional component, its a clss component. maybe its something else?